# Azure ARM Template Unit Test

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

How to test Azure ARM Templates and validate them whether these are written correctly or not from local VM.
I have tried it from Power Shell but it just validate only. I want to Unit Test the ARM templates

Comment: Did you use this powershell cmdlet to test ?      `Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do **unit test** the ARM Templates with **PESTER**. If you are unfamiliar with pester, you can refer to [this document](https://github.com/pester/Pester).

**Example ARM Template**

The example template being tested allows for the selection of whether managed or un-managed disk are used for the VM. The template can be found here https://github.com/bentaylorwork/azure-arm-templates/tree/master/disk-management-selection.

**Example Pester Test**
The Pester test below will check if the correct disk types are being deployed based on user input of whether the vm’s disks should be based on managed or un-managed disks. The file can be found here:
https://github.com/bentaylorwork/azure-arm-templates/blob/master/disk-management-selection/tests/unit.tests.ps1   You can save it to your local machine as `test.ps1` file.

**Running The Test**

*NOTE*: The blog's script has an error with not defined  `$parameterHash`, So , you can use my following scripts to execute:

```
<# 
    Steps to run:
    1) Login to Azure
    2) Select correct subscription
    3) Alter the path below to where you have the have saved the pester test locally
#>

$pesterParamters = @{
    Path       = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.ps1'
    Parameters = @{
                        templateUri                 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bentaylorwork/azure-arm-templates/master/disk-management-selection/azuredeploy.json'
                        templateParameterObject     = @{
                            resourcePrefix = 'pester'
                            adminPassword  = 'SuperSecurePlainTextPassword123!!'
                        }
                  }
}

$parameterHash= @{
                            resourcePrefix = 'pester'
                            adminPassword  = 'SuperSecurePlainTextPassword123!!'
                        }

Invoke-Pester -Script $pesterParamters
```

**Example Output From A Successful Test**

[image]

You can see more details about Unit testing conditions in ARM templates with pester in [this blog](https://bentaylor.work/2017/10/unit-testing-azure-arm-templates-with-pester/).

Additionally, I also recommend a tool to check ARM templates: **Azure ARM templates checker.** It is a quick and dirty tool to check if all parameters or variables used in the template have been defined. You can see more details about ARM templates checker in [this link](https://github.com/sebbrochet/azure-arm-checker).

Comment: Thanks a lot .. It is really helpful details

Comment: HI,@SachidanandSharma . I'm glad to hear that it's helpful to you.  You can mark it as answer so that we can help more communities! Thanks!