# Azure ARM Template Testing with Pester

Tags: azure

I have been following the link

[Azure ARM Template Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278046/azure-arm-template-testing) on how to carry out ARM testing with Pester.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to get a successful tests.

For example in the script the following code states the following:

It "Does Availability Set Have Correct SKU" {
            $av = $deploymentOutput.validatedResources | Where-Object { $_.type -eq 'Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets' }

```
        $av.sku.name | Should Be **'Align'**
```

However, even though the result of the ARM template is 'Align' I get the following error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSvmo.png)

Whereas I should be getting the following successful output:

[success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh6tO.png)

For a complete look at the code it can be found [here](https://github.com/bentaylorwork/azure-arm-templates/blob/master/disk-management-selection/tests/unit.tests.ps1)

Any guidance will greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

While this isnt a direct answer to your question, this is an indirect answer to your question :)

Just dont do this. `Test-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment` doesnt do any real good. If you insist on using it you can always use a 1 liner to do that or use VSCode tasks or whatever to kick off this **cough** test **cough**.

There is really no point in validating if this particular resource type is the one that you expect, because you dont really change resource types in the resource after you created it. Also, if `Test-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment` returns success doesnt mean your deployment will work. It only checks basic sanity. Just create a powershell script\task to deploy a template and kick it off automatically after commit. Pester adds nothing of value to this process, only complicates things.